# Method reference to instance method from class type vs Method reference to instance method from instance

Tags: java, method-reference

Method reference to instance method from instance

```
// compile successfully, out is instance, println is instance method
Consumer<String> c = System.out::println;
```

Method reference to instance method from class type

```
// compile fail, PrintStream is class type, println is instance method
Consumer<String> c = PrintStream::println;
```

why `Consumer<String> c = PrintStream::println` fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But!

```
BiConsumer<PrintStream, String> c = PrintStream::println; // compiles!
```

Method references to the class have an implicit first parameter of the instance. This is similar to `Method` whose `invoke()` method’s first parameter is the instance.

Comment: "Method references to the class have an implicit first parameter of the instance.", seem this is the critical different to Reference to an Instance Method of a Particular Object, but no much article or tutorial mention this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question. `PrintStream.println(String)` is an instance method, implying that an instance is required for the method to be invoked on.

With this

```
Consumer<String> c = PrintStream::println
```

Java does not know where to find the `PrintStream` instance on which to call `println()` when `c.accept(String)` is called. The code would compile if `println` were `static` in `PrintStream`.

That is not the same story with

```
Consumer<String> c = System.out::println
```

Which has already specified the instance on which `println` will be called (the instance being `System.out`).

There are cases where an instance on which a method reference is to be invoked does not need to be specified explicitly, like (borrowing an Object method for simplicity)

```
Consumer<String> c = String::notify; //notify is an instance method
```

This compiles because Java can use the parameter passed to `Consumer.accept` as the target of the method, so `String::notify` can be used for that purpose. But things aren't this simple (e.g., `notify` is void), so it's important to go through the docs/spec on how method references are resolved (this is a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: but BiConsumer<PrintStream, String> c = PrintStream::println; can run, so PrintStream::println should know to use a instance of PrintStream to call println()? just this violate Consumer<String> c?

Comment: Learning this by example can be misleading given the number of quirks with method reference lookup. I suggest you look through the tutorial, such as here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html. `BiConsumer<PrintStream, String>` is compatible with `PrintStream::println` because the first parameter is used as the target of the method, the second parameter being the method argument.... *"PrintStream::println should know to use a instance of PrintStream to call println()"*: which instance? With `BiConsumer`, Java knows that an instance will be provided...

Comment: I have seen the link you provided before, there is an example Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
where compareToIgnore is also not a static method but can be called by String::compareToIgnoreCase, not stringInstance::compareToIgnoreCase

Comment: Right. `Arrays.sort`'s second argument is `Comparator<T>` (`Comparator<String>` if you give it a String array). The method's signature, `compare(String, String)` is implemented with method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` just as in the example of `BiConsumer<PrintStream, String>` above: the first parameter to the functional interface's method will be the target of the method call, while the second will be the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `non-static` method can not be referenced from a `static` context.

You can check it in `System.java`

```
public static final PrintStream out = null;
```

`out` is `static`, that's why it is compiling.

While, in order to access `println` of `PrintStream`, you have to create an instance of `PrintStream` first and then invoke `println`.

```
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream("File");
        Consumer<String> c = printStream::println;
```